# Need help to format xml through DOM java

Tags: java, xml, dom, jdbc

I am trying to fetch data from database using jdbc and creating xml from that result. In my database I have a column that has repeating values but the values against the repeating values are different.
Here is the screen short of the db.[db image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWA4T.png). But when i am trying to store in xml it keeps on repeating.

Here is my code:

```
toDate=d1;
            fromDate=d2;
            Connection connection= null;
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet rp= null;
String query="SELECT p.productcode,p.productline,p.productvendor,p.productname,o.ordernumber,o.orderdate,
 t.ordernumber,t.productcode,t.quantityordered,t.priceeach,(t.quantityordered * t.priceeach) 
 as total from orders o join orderdetails t on o.ordernumber=t.ordernumber 
 join products p on p.productcode=t.productcode where orderdate
 between "?" and "?" order by productline;

PreparedStatement p2=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                p2.setString(1, toDate);
                p2.setString(2, fromDate);
rp=p2.executeQuery();
```

DOM Creation Code:

```
                        DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                        Document xmlDoc = documentBuilder.newDocument();

Element product_list=xmlDoc.createElement("product_list");
                        root.appendChild(product_list);
                        Element product_set=xmlDoc.createElement("productset");
                        product_list.appendChild(product_set);
                        while(rp.next()) {
                            Element pro_line_name=xmlDoc.createElement("product_line_name");
                            pro_line_name.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(rp.getString("productLine")));
                            product_set.appendChild(pro_line_name);

                            Element product=xmlDoc.createElement("product");
                            pro_line_name.appendChild(product);

                            Element pro_name=xmlDoc.createElement("product_name");
                            pro_name.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(rp.getString("productname")));
                            product.appendChild(pro_name);

                            Element pro_vendor=xmlDoc.createElement("product_vendor");
                            pro_vendor.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(rp.getString("productvendor")));
                            product.appendChild(pro_vendor);                
                        }
rp.close();
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

Here is the xml i am looking for:

```
<product_list>  
<product_set>    
<product_line_name> vintage cars</product_line_name>   
<product>     
<product_name> 1980s Black Hawk Helicopter </product_name >     
<product_vendor> Red Start Diecast </product_vendor >      
</product>   
<prodcut> 
<product_name>xyz</product_name>
<pro_vendor>xyz</pro_vendor>
</product_set>
```

Here is the xml is am getting:

```
 <product_list>
    <productset>
    <product_line_name>Vintage Cars<product>
    <product_name>1941 Chevrolet Special Deluxe Cabriolet</product_name>
    <product_vendor>Exoto Designs</product_vendor>
    </product>
    </product_line_name>
    <product_line_name>Vintage Cars<product>
    <product_name>1937 Horch 930V Limousine</product_name>
    <product_vendor>Autoart Studio Design</product_vendor>
    </product>
    </product_line_name>
    <product_line_name>Vintage Cars<product>
    <product_name>1928 Ford Phaeton Deluxe</product_name>
    <product_vendor>Highway 66 Mini Classics</product_vendor>
    </product>
    </product_line_name>
```

I just want the product_line_name once and the child repeating multiple times instead i am getting both the product_line_name and child both repeating multiple times.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `product_line_name` and its `product`children repeating the same number of times because you got them within the same loop:

> while(rp.next()) {
>   ...
>   }

Instead, you would need to create a `product_line_name` element for every productline you encounter and then append `product`s to their corresponding `product_line_name` parent for every Database entry you read.

F.e., you could do something along the lines of:

```
...
HashMap<String, Element> foundProductLineNames = new HashMap<String, Element>();
...

while (rp.next()) {
    String productLineName = rp.getString("productLine");
    /* If wee see this product line name for the first time... */
    if (!foundProductLineNames.containsKey(productLineName)) {
        /* ...we have to create a DOM element for it and append it to the product set. */
        Element proLineNameElem=xmlDoc.createElement("product_line_name");
        proLineNameElem.appendChild(xmlDoc
            .createTextNode(rp.getString("productLine")));
        product_set.appendChild(proLineNameElem);

        /* Store the product line for later use. */
        foundProductLineNames.put(productLineName, proLineNameElem);
    }
    /* Proceed with your original code for adding products but use
       foundProductLineNames.get(productLineName) instaed of pro_line_name.
       For example: */

    Element productElem=xmlDoc.createElement("product");
    foundProductLineNames.get(productLineName).appendChild(productElem);
}
```